# Accessing the address of a protected page from within the signal handler

Tags: c

Is there a way of getting the address of ip from within the signal handler? I want to be able to change the permissions of the page so that the signal doesn't keep firing.

```
static void hdl (int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {

    printf("Caught Signal %d\n", sig);

}

int main() {

    struct sigaction act;
    memset (&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = &hdl;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL) < 0)
        return 1;

    int *ip = (int *) mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    *ip = 1;

    printf("%d\n", *ip);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the intended uses of a three-argument signal handler.  The `si_addr` field of the `siginfo` argument will contain the address of the inaccessible memory word that provoked the fault.  (Note: this field only has that meaning for `SIGSEGV` and `SIGBUS`.  For other signals, it may be garbage, or may instead point to the offending *instruction*.)

```
static void
hdl(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ctx)
{
    assert(sig == SIGSEGV || sig == SIGBUS);
    printf("Memory fault, addr = %p\n", info->si_addr);
}
```

You can use [`mprotect`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html) to fix up the permissions on the page containing `si_addr`, and then return from the signal handler to resume execution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of getting the address of ip from within the signal handler?

There is no defined way for a signal handler to directly access the local variables of any other function.

On an implementation where a `sigatomic_t` is large enough to accommodate pointer values without truncation, you could create a file-scope variable of type `volatile sigatomic_t`, cast `ip` to `sigatomic_t`, and assign it to that variable:

```
volatile sigatomic_t ip_int;

// ...

    ip_int = (sigatomic_t) ip;
```

The signal handler could then safely read that variable.  Even if your `sigatomic_t` could accommodate that, however, it seems unlikely that whatever function you've in mind to use for changing memory permissions is async signal safe.  If it is not, then it cannot safely be called from a signal handler, and in that case, it is moot whether you can safely get the data into the signal handler.

If you're uncertain whether you will already have the needed permissions yet are confident that you have sufficient privileges to obtain them, then how about just obtaining them up front, preemptively?